Can we insert text into Ribbon input VSTO C#?
I am working on VSTO Outlook add-in using c#, I want to insert any text into the input field, I am using XML to create custom Ribbon. Is this possible? This is the input code I am using in Ribbon:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id='sample_tab' label='Projects'>
                <group id='project_code_group' label='Project Code'>
                        <editBox id='project_code_input' label='Code'/>
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>


I have function that is working on Outlook item change, function called: CurrentExplorer_SelectionChange
I want whenever this function will call (I am getting email subject from this function on item change) it should set text into my Ribbon input field.

You can use a callback to update editBox text, for exemple:
<editBox id='project_code_input' label='Code' getText='MyTextFunctionUpdate'/>

On your ribbon cs file add this function
public string MyTextFunctionUpdate(IRibbonControl control)
{
       return MyStaticVariable;
}

Set MyStaticVariable with the text needed when CurrentExplorer_SelectionChange is triggered and invalidate the control to make PowerPoint call the callback with ribbon.InvalidateControl("project_code_input")
Link to the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/ribbon-xml?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#assign-callback-methods-to-controls
